# What is wrong with this simple Lex example?

Tags: bison, lex

Heloo EveryBody,
I have a simple code in lex language and i try to run it by "bison -d hello.l" but i get error!
I get the following  error.

Could somebody let me know what I am wrong?

```
bison -d hello.l

hello.l:4.1-5: syntax error, unexpected identifier
```

Code:

```
%{
#include <math.h>
%}
DIGIT    [0-9]
ID       [a-z][a-z0-9]*

%%

     {DIGIT}+    {
                 printf( "An integer: %s (%d)\n", yytext,
                         atoi( yytext ) );
                 }

     {DIGIT}+"."{DIGIT}*        {
                 printf( "A float: %s (%g)\n", yytext,
                         atof( yytext ) );
                 }

     if|then|begin|end|procedure|function        {
                 printf( "A keyword: %s\n", yytext );
                 }

     {ID}        printf( "An identifier: %s\n", yytext );

     "+"|"-"|"*"|"/"   printf( "An operator: %s\n", yytext );

     "{"[\^{}}\n]*"}"     /* eat up one-line comments */

     [ \t\n]+          /* eat up whitespace */

     .           printf( "Unrecognized character: %s\n", yytext );

     %%

     int main( int argc, char **argv )
         {
         ++argv, --argc;  /* skip over program name */
         if ( argc > 0 )
                 yyin = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
         else
                 yyin = stdin;

         yylex();
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile a (f)lex input file with bison. Use yylex or flex.

EDIT: OK, further problems (I tried to compile your code):

1. The rules must start at the beginning of the line, with no
   whitespace in front of them (remove the whitespace at the beginning
   of lines 9, 14, etc.).
2. Add `%option noyywrap` at the beginning of the file.
3. Compile the file with `flex filename.l`.
4. Then compile the generated .c file. You need no additional headers.

Comment: I use bison to generate CONST.H file!
because when i want to compile lex.yy.c file i get some error like "undeclared (first use in this function) " !
when i search in web i understand i need a Const.h file, so i want to generate that file. 
how i can do this ?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to know *what* is reported to be undeclared.

Comment: 9 C:\Users\Majid\Desktop\F\hello.l `DIGIT' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: I found this post like my post .
please help me how i can generate "y.tab.h" that contains the definitions in windows ?

Comment: The example you've posted is the example from the flex manual, I guess. I still do not understand what exactly you've done and which command gives which error. You do not need an y.tab.h file if you do not use bison.